# Running R scripts within a bash script

Tags: linux, r, bash

I have 2 R scripts in the sub-folders of folder1, and ran the following script. "No such file or directory" error was returened for the R scripts. Does anyone know how to solve this problem? Thanks

Bash script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env Rscript
for dir in folder1/* ; do
Rscript script1.R
Rscript script2.R
done
```

Answer (score 3):

You `#!` specifies R, not bash. And your loop is wrong.

Maybe try this:

```
#!/bin/bash Rscript
for dir in folder1/script*.R ; do
    echo "Now running $dir"
    Rscript folder1/$dir
done
```

Answer (score 3):

Are `script1.R` and `script2.R` inside the subdirectories of `folder1`? If so, try this:

```
#! /bin/bash
for dir in folder1/* ; do
    Rscript "$dir"/script1.R
    Rscript "$dir"/script2.R
done
```

Another way to run all R scripts inside `folder1` is to use `find`:

```
find folder1 -type f -name "*.R" -exec Rscript {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

You never changed the directory, so you should either switch to the new subfolder before executing the scripts or execute them using the full path.

Thus, try to replace

```
Rscript script1.R
Rscript script2.R
```

either by

```
cd folder1/$dir; Rscript script1.R; cd -
cd folder1/$dir; Rscript script2.R; cd -
```

or

```
Rscript folder1/$dir/script1.R
Rscript folder1/$dir/script2.R
```

Also, your shebang is wrong, it should be

```
#!/bin/bash
```

or something similar if you want your script to be a shell script. Right now it is executed as an `R` script.

Comment: It is possible to make this in windows